# show sibling li on click and hide open sibling li - jQuery

Tags: jquery

might be really simple for you folks ;) 
I have a list of links and when the user clicks on one of them the siblings links should be displayed. I have got to the part when click on link it fade in one list but i want the open sibling list to fade out.

take a look I you might understand better...
http://jsfiddle.net/jelm/UkRNL/

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">item one</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li>children of item one</li>
            <li>children of item one</li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">item two</a>
        <ul class="children">
            <li>children of item two</li>
            <li>children of item two</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
   $('li > ul').hide();
   $('.menu li > a').click(function() {
       $(this).next().fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly, is [this what you want](http://jsfiddle.net/UkRNL/1/)?

I've simply hidden the child `ul` elements when a link is clicked, before fading in the correct set, by using `$('li > ul').hide();` inside the `click` event handler.